# Get count of all clients invoices with multiple status id

Tags: python, django, django-views

my invoice Model :

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients)
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    invoice_status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

Status model:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    invoice_status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

client model:

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

Status will be

1.Draft
2.Sent
3.Paid

i tried multiple methods but all failed

```
invoices = Invoice.objects.values("client").aggregate(Paid=Sum(Case(When(invoice_status__id=1, then=1),output_field=IntegerField())))
```

i like to get all clients invoices status count

**expected result**:

client_id:1, Draft:4(count), Sent:5(count), Paid:0(count)

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint
from django.db.models import Count

data = Invoice.objects.prefetch_related('invoice_status') \
    .values('client', 'invoice_status') \
    .annotate(count=Count('id')) \
    .order_by('client') \
    .values_list('client', 'invoice_status__invoice_status', 'count')
user_statuses = OrderedDict()
for client, status, count in data:
    statuses = user_statuses.get(client) or {}
    statuses[status] = count
    user_statuses[client] = statuses
pprint(user_statuses)
```

Comment: this is good option but a queryset would be more useful than orderedDict in my case